# dynamic allocation of struct with Malloc

Tags: c, struct, malloc, dynamic-memory-allocation

Iam begginner in C and dynamic allocation,
i would like to allocate a memory for a structure.
struct MusicTitle has the list of a music title and the signer structure has the name of the songs and number of album that he made.

```
struct musicTitle()        // structure of music title
{
Char* nameofsong;
char* Singer_name;
Char * release_year; }


musicTitle* allocteMusicTitle(){ // function to allocate memory for the music title struct
musicTitle* musicTitlePtr= (musicTitle*)malloc(sizeof(musicTitle*));
return musicTitlePtr;
}

struct singer{      // each singer has musictitle and albums
musicTitle* musicTitleofsigner
int* nbrAlbum;
}

singerMusic* allocateSingerMusic {
singerMusic* singerMusicPtr= (singerMusic*)malloc(sizeof(singerMusic*)); //allocate memory for singerMusic struct
}
```

my question is, do i need to allocate memory for nbrAlbum of the singer structure? or it gonna be done with allocateSingerMusic function ?
Thank you

Comment: You have more important things to worry about, like why you're allocating the size of a *pointer* rather than the size of a *struct* with  `malloc(sizeof(musicTitle*));` . This is why, where at all possible (and it is in this case) you should consider allocation based on the size of the target pointer dereference (`sizeof *musicTitlePtr`) rather than the size of a type. Same problem with `malloc(sizeof(singerMusic*))`.  And we have no idea what a `singeMusic` even is (or for that matter `Char`), so perhaps the *real* code will be more informative.

Answer (score 0):

There are few syntax and logical problems with this code. For example
Missing semicolon.

```
musicTitle* musicTitleofsigner
```

and allocating memory with size of pointer rather than size of struct.

```
singerMusic* singerMusicPtr= (singerMusic*)malloc(sizeof(singerMusic*));
```

I hope, you will correct those mistakes. Answer to your main question is that you need to allocate memory for nbrAlbum. This is the power and beauty of C language that no dynamic memory will be allocated automatically unless it is done explicitly.

Comment: I was told that i dont need to allocate memory for nbrAlbum, buti need to allocate memory for struct singer and the musicTitle* pointer which is in the same struct